# Find and output range that match specified regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, grep

I have file with the following structure:

```
//-BeginBlock-//
Any info with any lines quantity
//-01.02.2015 02:00:00-//
//-BeginBlock-//
Any info with any lines quantity
//-02.03.2015 00:06:00-//
```

And so on...

Now, how to print content of blocks that contains regex, specified by script user? Example: For file

```
//-BeginBlock-//
qwerty 8567
Some
Info
In Block 1
//-01.02.2015 02:00:00-//
//-BeginBlock-//
dsdfh 9854
Some info in Block 2
//-02.02.2015 02:00:00-//
//-BeginBlock-//
dsdfh 9855 Some info in Block 3
//-03.02.2015 02:00:00-//
```

and regex `dsdfh 985*` script must return

```
//-BeginBlock-//
dsdfh 9854
Some info in Block 2
//-01.02.2015 02:00:00-//
//-BeginBlock-//
dsdfh 9855 Some info in Block 3
//-01.02.2015 02:00:00-//
```

Or even just content of blocks, splitted by delimiter.
I found that ranges can be obtained by `sed -n '/\/\/-BeginBlock-\/\//I,/\/\/-/p' ~/.marks` 
But I don't know how to make it work as expected. Also I tried to use grep with -zo flags like `grep -Eizoa "\/\/-BeginBlock-\/\/" ~/.marks` but can't make it work too.
Is there a way to solve that program with standart bash utils?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Added an example to question.

Comment: see my answer. And also dates in your expected output is different. Please check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-P` parameter.

```
$ grep -ozP '(?s)[^\n]*//-BeginBlock-//[^\n]*(?:(?!//-).)*dsdfh 985.*?//-[^\n]*' file
//-BeginBlock-//
dsdfh 9854
Some info in Block 2
//-02.02.2015 02:00:00-//
//-BeginBlock-//
dsdfh 9855 Some info in Block 3
//-03.02.2015 02:00:00-//
```

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I needed! Last thing... How can I exclude //-BeginBlock-// and //-..date..-// from output and somehow separate results?

Comment: `grep -ozP '(?s)[^\n]*//-BeginBlock-//[^\n]*\K(?:(?!//-).)*dsdfh 985.*?(?=\n//-[^\n]*)' file`